# jasmine not loading helper files

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I'm trying to run jasmine helpers script but they are not being picked up.
I was looking at the [jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/2.3/node.html) API and its looks straightforward, only add `helpers` to `jasmine.json`.

This is one of the helpers I was testing. It only purpose is to create a file when jasmine is invoked.

helpers/fileHelper.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile("./jasmineHelperOutput.txt", "Hey there!", function(err) {

    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

});
```

jasmine.json

```
{
    "spec_dir": "./spec",
    "spec_files": [
        "**/*.spec.js"
    ],
    "helpers": [
        "helpers/**/*.js"
    ]
}
```

setup:

- OS: win10
- node: 8.1.3
- npm: 5.0.3

But it doesn't work.

What am I missing ?

I have created a simple jasmine project at https://github.com/dannyhuly/jasmine-with-helpers with the issue at hand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

For those having this issue I spent a while digging through the jasmine code only to find that the helpers file is searched for relative to the `"spec_dir": "./spec"` in the jasmine.json file. SO if you dont have your tests under the spec folder and need to change the spec directory, make sure you correct the helpers file path.

Comment: If you are trying to specify a helper file on the command line, be aware that jasmine treating your `--handle` arg like a glob and ignoring it it can't find it under the spec directory: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/blob/18e0459/lib/jasmine.js#L160

Answer (score 0):

It took me a bit long to get this:

In your test.spec.js add

```
var helpers = require('../helpers/funcHelper.js');
var helperFS = require('../helpers/fileHelper.js'); 


describe('test' , function(){

    it("should run", function(){

        helpers.helper_func(); // use helper
        helperFS.writeHelper();
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    })
})
```

and in fileHelper.js :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var writeHelper = function() {
fs.writeFile("./jasmineHelperOutput.txt", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }})
};
exports.writeHelper = writeHelper;
```

Also check this:
[jasmine-git resolve code](https://github.com/mehta-rohan/jasmine.git)

Comment: I would like the helpers files to run before the spec. adding the the `require` in the spec file misses the point.
Thanks.